# animation.Play() doesn't work

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm pretty sure that

```
animation.Play("DoorOpen");
```

Would play the animation "DoorOpen", but when i'm trying to put it in my code, it just giving me an error message:

> The Animation attached to this GameObject (null if there is none attached).

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DoorPhysics : MonoBehaviour {

    int Open = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {


        if (Open == 0) {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e")) {

                animation.Play("DoorOpen");

        }
    }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to show location of gameobjects in unity, they do not know eachother, you have to always use :

```
GameObject.GetComponent<T>()
GetComponentInParent<T>()
GetComponentInChildren<T>()
```

best practice is to get object references at `Start()`
also you should attach **IMPORTANT!!!** **Animation component to the object this script it attached to**

```
 public class DoorPhysics : MonoBehaviour {

        public Animation animation;
        int Open = 0;



    void Start()
    {
        animation=GameObject.GetComponent<Animation>(); //if your have derived type change Animation to good class DoorAnimation for example
    }

    void Update()
    {
      if (Open == 0) {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown("e")) {
                     this.animation.Play("DoorOpen");
            }
        }
    }
  }
```

if that code wont work, you will need show me your GameObject hierarchy

[image]

And if your just start your trip with it learn [MonoBehaviour call order](http://docs.unity3d.com/uploads/Main/monobehaviour_flowchart.svg) 
and [life cycles of events](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: If you want the hole code here it is...

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DoorPhysics : MonoBehaviour {

    int Open = 0;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {


        if (Open == 0) {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown("e")) {

                animation.Play("DoorOpen");

        }
    }

    }
}

Comment: youe should edit your question and put it there with good formating! :) AND! give me place where you update()

Comment: Done... Check it out now :)

Comment: @ThorValdemarEgelykkeOlsenBi answere edited! check it pls

Comment: Sorry... That din't work... So here is the GameObject hierarchy:
[link]http://puu.sh/lecGs/4f170ef1c3.png[link]

check it please :)

Comment: which object is animation object?

Comment: you should attach (IMPORTANT!!!) Animation component to the object this script it attached to@ThorValdemarEgelykkeOlsenBi

Comment: @ThorValdemarEgelykkeOlsenBi then remember to accept my answere :)